# awk: Print $1 with varying number of additional fields on the same line

Tags: awk

I have an input file with ~100 lines and ~100 fields per line. Each field represents either a positive or negative value. I wish to print $1 followed by only the positive **or** negative fields in each line. The number of positive or negative fields per line is random.

#### sample input

```
0 x 9 8 7 -1 -2 -3
2 x 7 6 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 x 4 3 2 1 -6 -7
```

#### desired output

positive

```
0 9 8 7
2 7 6
4 4 3 2 1
```

negative

```
0 -1 -2 -3
2 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 -6 -7
```

#### context and attempt

The above outputs print $1, followed by either the positive or the negative values in remaining fields on the same line as $1.

The current code I tried (for positive values, starting on line 6 in my input):

```
awk 'NR>5{for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ( $i > 0 ) print $1, $i}' input > output
```

This works fine, except that I print an output like:

```
 0 9
 0 8
 0 7
 2 7
 2 6
 4 4
 4 3
 4 2
 4 1
```

I have also tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\t"} NR>5 {print $1} {for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i > 0 && i <= NF} {print $i}}' input > output
```

but then I never move to a new line in the output. If I change ORS back to \n via some 'else if (i = NF) {ORS=...}' condition, then it prints all field outputs for each i on a new line, like the BEGIN statement has no effect.

#### question

How can I tell awk to print $1, then print all other output from the same input line onto the same output line, then advance 1 new line in the output and repeat the process for the next input line?

Thank you.

#### response to Tiw's answer

I tried to execute this in a loop for my two files:

```
for j in 1 2; do
positive=ofile.p0
negative=ofile.m0

awk 'NR>5{
    printf $1>"positive";
    printf $1>"negative";
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)
       if($i~/[-+]?[0-9]+/)
           if ($i>0) printf OFS $i>"positive";
           else if($i<0) printf OFS $i>"negative";
    print "">"positive";
    print "">"negative";
}'ofile.0$j

mv positive $positive$j
mv negative $negative$j

done
```

but it hangs. Edit: Tiw's answer updated with %s in printf. It works with this change.

Comment: output to different file.

Comment: @Blaisem, continously + values and - values both are coming but why some lines are printed for + and some for -? Could you please explain more on this?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 My goal is to separate an input into positive and negative values. I would like one output that contains the original input, but only the fields which had positive values. The second output also contains the original input, but only the fields which had negative values. I planned on having an awk code to separate positive values, and a second awk code to separate negative values. Does that help? Thank you.

Comment: @Blaisem.. is Perl solution fine for you?..

Comment: Should `0` be considered positive or negative or not printed at all?

Comment: @EdMorton I am ignoring 0 for now (ie. not printing). I figured if my needs change, I can always adapt any code to include the 0 fields as necessary.

Comment: @stack0114106 I've never used Perl, but it's good to have diverse responses for future viewers. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NF>5{printf "%s",$1>"positive";printf "%s",$1>"negative"; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/) if ($i>0) printf "%s",OFS $i>"positive"; else if($i<0) printf "%s",OFS $i>"negative"; print "">"positive";print "">"negative";}' input
```

With a file named `input`:

```
0 x 9 8 7 -1 -2 -3
2 x 7 6 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 x 4 3 2 1 -6 -7
```

It will create two files,
one `positive`:

```
0 9 8 7
2 7 6
4 4 3 2 1
```

one `negative`:

```
0 -1 -2 -3
2 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 -6 -7
```

Put in multiple lines for better readability:

```
awk 'NF>5{
    printf "%s",$1>"positive";
    printf "%s",$1>"negative"; 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
        if($i~/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/)     ## Another and better way is $i == $i + 0 
            if ($i>0) printf "%s",OFS $i>"positive"; 
            else if($i<0) printf "%s",OFS $i>"negative"; 
    print "">"positive";
    print "">"negative";
}' input
```

It's quite straightforward so I guess it's easy for you to understand.
Note I didn't use `{}` to quote the block after the `for` and `if`s, since they each has only one command after, so the quotes can be saved.
`print` will print a newline character `\n` at the end, `printf` won't.
Also `NR` means **N**umber of **R**ecords, i.e. the line number, I changed to `NF`, which means **N**umber of **F**ields, I think this is what you wanted.

`if($i~/^[-+]?[0-9]+$/)` is to test the field is a number.
If the field won't be empty, then `$i==$+0` is a better way.
And combine with testing the field is not `0` or empty, use `$i && ($i==$i+0)`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to implement it in a couple different ways, but the code hangs. I ran it with bash -xv and don't see the reason for the error. Still trying to look at it. I edited my script into the original question in reply to you.

Comment: ah I just noticed the edit to printf "%s". Will try that now.

Comment: `$i~/[-+]?[0-9]+/` would match `Joe90` and other non-numbers. The test for a number given a non-null `$i` is `$i == $i+0`. For the print, rather than 2 very similar lines, consider just one: `printf "%s",OFS $i>($i>=0 ? "positive" : "negative")` (assuming the OP wants 0 to be considered positive)

Comment: @EdMorton So I can replace that line with $i == $i+0? For that matter, since all I have are numbers, I could just delete the line altogether, right? Also on the print suggestion, wouldn't ($i>=0) print positive values onto my negative output, or does the code account for this?

Comment: Right but since you want to not print zeros change it to `($i != 0) && ($i == $i+0)`. No, `print ($i>=0 ? "positive" : "negative")` will not print positive numbers to your negative output. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) for how ternary expressions work.

Comment: @EdMorton  Forgot to add `^` and `$`, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Blaisem Updated the answer, added `^` and `$` to the regex, my negligence, sorry about it. And that part can also be replaced by `if ($i && ($i==$i+0))`.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is to check if the field is a number, if this is the case, you can do the check. In `awk`, you can check if a variable is a number by adding zero to it, and check if it returns the same value.

For positive numbers you do this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i+0 == $i && $i >= 0) printf $i OFS; printf ORS}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option,

Input:

```
$ cat blaisem.txt
0 x 9 8 7 -1 -2 -3
2 x 7 6 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 x 4 3 2 1 -6 -7

$
```

***+ve and -ve  separate runs***

```
$ perl -ne ' @p=/(\S+)(?<=\d)/g;print "$p[0] "; for(@p[1..$#p]) { print "$_ " if $_ >=0 } print "\n" ' blaisem.txt
0 9 8 7
2 7 6
4 4 3 2 1

$ perl -ne ' @p=/(\S+)(?<=\d)/g;print "$p[0] "; for(@p[1..$#p]) { print "$_ " if $_ < 0 } print "\n" ' blaisem.txt
0 -1 -2 -3
2 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 -6 -7

$
```

***+ve and -ve in one script***

```
$  perl -ne ' open(POS,">>pos.txt"); open(NEG,">>neg.txt"); @p=/(\S+)(?<=\d)/g; 
          print POS "$p[0] "; print NEG "$p[0] "; 
           for(@p[1..$#p]) { print NEG "$_ " if $_ < 0; print POS "$_ " if $_>=0  } 
             print POS "\n"; print NEG "\n" ' blaisem.txt

$ cat pos.txt
0 9 8 7
2 7 6
4 4 3 2 1

$ cat neg.txt
0 -1 -2 -3
2 -2 -3 -4 -5
4 -6 -7

$
```